# FIDO vs SSO : what architecture ? what benefit?

Tags: single-sign-on, fido

Recently I have been looking for details about FIDO (uaf, u2f, fido2) and I don't get one point :
Does FIDO will replace SSO ? Or Both would work together ? What to suggest to clients in terms of authentification solution ? etc.

With SSO, we have Identity Manager server. And with fido we have FIDO server.. They have to work together or not at all ?

Please help me to understand.

Many thanks!

Looking for "fido vs sso", "fido or sso" give nothing concrete.

Answer (score 1):

FIDO is an authentication method (with a passkey being the credential name). SSO is an experience, typically leveraging federation to allow sign-in state to be leveraged across multiple sites.

For consumer services, local sign in with passkeys (FIDO2 credentials) can certainly replace "third party federation" (e.g. Sign in with Google, Sign in with Facebook, etc) to reduce dependencies on third parties or to remove privacy concerns.

In work/school scenarios, most applications federate to a central identity provider, giving an "SSO experience". This is often required by organizational policy. FIDO credentials could be used to authenticate to that central identity provider (as could other methods like a smartcard).